# Make button on website , which runs python script in ODOO

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I've made a new module in odoo. It has the action button (check ip using ipwhois). Now i need to integrate this module in website. It is easy to show fields on webpage, but i don't know how make button and call the function. The button is shown on webpage, but function is not callable.

As i understand: clicking on button must call python function, reload page and write a new value in field "result_check".

```
<record id="sale_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">sale.form</field>
  <field name="model">product.template</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="website_sale.product_template_form_view"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="categ_id" position="after">
      <button name="make_request" type="object" string="Make check" />
      <field name="result_check" />
    </field>
  </field>
</record>

<templateid="add_fields_product"inherit_id="website_sale.product">
<xpathexpr="//div[@id='product_details']"position="before"> 
<div>
   <a role="button" href="#"><span>Make check</span></a> 
   <p itemprop="name" t-field="product.result_check">Result</p> 
</div> 
</xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: Where you have to write make_request function?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to write make_request function in product_template.py file.Means, where you have to inherit product.template model.Like the following:

```
    def make_request(self):
        # Here your code...
```

And from this function, you can set a value of a "result_check" field.

I hope this helps you. Thank you.

Comment: I have made it - it works in app, but i need to make this function available from website. I don't know how connect it with xml templates.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put code in your models.py file. Your xml file has

```
<button name="make_request" type="object" string="Make check" />
```

When user clicks on this button, it goes to your models.py file to activate the button. Looks like you using class: product.template [from your xml file]

In models.py file, find the section product.template, inside this class put this in:

```
@api.multi
def make_request(self):
    Put your code here
    return
```

So now your button in the xml is linked to the python code. That's how you get a button to activate your python code (making your button call your python code)

Comment: thanks! it works in module (portal), but not on website page.

Comment: Maybe, you should use a controller class and render your web. You can call from python function in controller class. @Laoris

Comment: @Laoris yes test with С. Дэлгэрцэцэг's idea. I understand what you want to do. The webpage (website) has the button, but when you click it, its not doing anything. This means the button is not linked properly to your python code. You need to make sure the names are correct, and in the correct class. You're calling the wrong place, or your python code is in the wrong place. You need to show your python code, and where you putting it. Then we can help more.